# Comment comprendre le participe passé ici ?

Tags: verbes, littérature, participe-passé

Bonjour,

Dans *[Conseil tenu par les rats](http://www.la-fontaine-ch-thierry.net/conseilrats.htm)* :

> Si bien que sans rien faire
> On se quitta. **J'ai** maints chapitres **vus**,
> Qui pour néant se sont ainsi tenus :
> Chapitres, non de Rats, mais chapitres de moines,
> Voire chapitres de chanoines.

Pourquoi La Fontaine sépare le participe passé du verbe auxiliaire dans *J'ai .... vus* ?

Answer (score 3):

À la question « pourquoi » on ne peut que répondre : « parce qu'il fallait faire rimer avec "tenus" ». Cette construction, qu'on peut trouver en ancien français, se rencontre encore au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle, ce n'est donc pas exceptionnel chez La Fontaine, par contre l’employer de nos jours produirait un effet tout autre.

Voici ce que dit *Le bon usage* à propos justement de ce vers de la Fontaine et cité dans les exemples relatifs à l'accord du participe passé<sup>1</sup>.

> Dans la langue moderne, cette construction, où le  complément d’objet direct est placé entre l’auxiliaire et le participe se rencontre encore   parfois chez les poètes : *Des biens, des maux, — des révolutions, — / Ont dans les cœurs sa mémoire effacée* (Nerval, *Odelettes*, Grand’mère). — *L’orgie a sa rumeur doublée / Du tintamarre des tournois* (Théophile Gautier, *Émaux et Camées*, Le souper des armures).  — Mais en prose, exceptée l'expression figée *avoir toute honte bue*, elle n'est aujourd'hui qu'un caprice d'archaïsme : *J’ai toute ambition résignée* (Duhamel, Pierre d’Horeb, p. 96).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> 10<sup>e</sup> édition, note historique, §788.</sup>